# automatically scroll the datagrid to the bottom on page redirect

Tags: asp.net

I have a search page. user can enter numbers on the search page text boxes and press enter, it redirects the user to another page that show a datagrid based on there search criteria. The datagrid has scroll bar in it. User wants when the page is redirected the scroll bar should be at the bottom of the grid so that they can start editing from the bottom of the grid. Is it possible to do that. The code for redirecting the user is below:

```
 Response.Redirect("/web/Recordsdata/TestPage.aspx")
```

Below is the code for scrolling the datagrid.

```
function SetDivPosition() {
            var intY = document.getElementById("divTest").scrollTop;
            document.cookie = "yPos=!~" + intY + "~!";
        }
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this answer from another forum. I am posting it here if someone else needs it.

```
    <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     //Scroll div you the bottom onpage load
       $("#divTest").scrollTop($("#divTest")[0].scrollHeight);
   });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an anchor tag on the page containing your data grid. Put the anchor tag at the top (or bottom) of the grid. Then, in your redirect, you use the fragment that matches your anchor tag.

```
Response.Redirect("/web/Recordsdata/TestPage.aspx#grid")
```

And on your grid, or near it use something like:

```
<a name="grid"></a>
```

Your page should then load at the position of the anchor tag.